# Converting float to int, with and without cast

Tags: c++, c, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

Are these two equivalent?

```
float f = 3.14;
int i;
i = f; // 3
```

And

```
float f = 3.14;
int i;
i = (int) f; // 3
```

Comment: they are same..why do you ask?

Comment: yup both are same...Newton's theory is getting complicated..:D

Comment: 3 == 3, does it not? :P

Comment: @user2864740 It depends on the compiler options that you use. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in the ways compiler treats these 2 cases. The resulting machine code will be the same. However, the first is implicit conversion, and the second is explicit conversion. Depending on compiler flags, you may get a warning when performing implicit conversion that loses precision.

On a side note, the literal `3.14` has type `double`, which means that there's also possible precision loss in the statement `float f = 3.14`. A clean way would be to write `float f = 3.14f` which specifies that this is 
the value 3.14 of type `float`.

Answer (score 7):

They are the same.

Tested with GCC 4.8.2 on 32-bit x86 system.

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` will NOT give any warnings while compiling this code, but with `-Wconversion` it will.

Comment: It will with `-Wconversion`

Answer (score 4):

Yes those are equivalent, no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton Now _god_ has blessed you, and its time to accept the answer :D +1

Answer (score 0):

the compiler is intelligent enough to treat both cases the same. But I prefer the 2nd method as it is easier to read in a large program. Also it is recommended to specify the type you are casting in explicit conversion. Finally, your 1st method may not work in C#.
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the second conversion is also known as **c-cast** and should be avoided, at least in c++, better use **static_cast**

When using static_cast the compiler will check if the conversion can happen (ie one type can be converted to the other), when using the old style it will always do the conversion even if they aren't compatible